# Sum of two identically distributed Bernoulli random variables is sufficient

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have to identically distributed Bernoulli$(p)$ random variables $X_1, X_2$ which are not necessarily independent. We would like to show that $X_1+X_2$ is a sufficient estimator for $p$.

To do this, I tried to compute
$$
P(X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2 \mid X_1+X_2 = t)
$$
Note that if $x_1+x_2 \neq t$ then the above evaluates to $0$. There remains 4 cases:
\begin{align*}
P(X_1=0, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 0)\\
P(X_1=1, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1)\\
P(X_1=0, X_2=1 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1)\\
P(X_1=1, X_2=1 \mid X_1+X_2 = 2)
\end{align*}
Clearly, 
$$
P(X_1=0, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 0) = P(X_1=1, X_2=1 \mid X_1+X_2 = 2) = 1
$$

> How do I handle the 2 other cases?

I know that if $X_1, X_2$ are independent then 
$$
P(X_1=1, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = P(X_1=0, X_2=1 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = 1/2
$$
On the other hand, if one picks $X_1$ and $X_2=X_1$ then
$$
P(X_1=1, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = P(X_1=0, X_2=1 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = 0
$$
The answer will therefore depend on something, but I am not sure how to formulate a general solution.

Comment: your conditional values depends on the correlation of the variables.  if $corr(X_1,X_2)=1 $ for example $X_1 + X_2 = 1 $ is an impossible state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb P(X_1+X_2 = 1)=0$, then one need not to consider this conditional probability. In other case,
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0, X_1+X_2 = 1)}{\mathbb P(X_1+X_2 = 1)}= \dfrac{\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0)}{\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0)+\mathbb P(X_1=0, X_2 =1)}
$$
Prove that both probabilities in the denominator are coincide: 
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=0, X_2=1) + \mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=1) = \mathbb P(X_2=1)=p, 
$$
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0) + \mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=1) = \mathbb P(X_1=1)=p, 
$$
and then
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=0, X_2=1) = p - \mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=1) = \mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0). 
$$
Therefore, the required conditional probability equals to $1/2$: 
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0)}{2\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=0)}=\frac12.
$$
And 
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=0, X_2=1 \mid X_1+X_2 = 1) = \dfrac{\mathbb P(X_1=0, X_2=1)}{2\mathbb P(X_1=0, X_2=1)}=\frac12.
$$
So, the sum is sufficient statistics.